# How to fetch data from php file using service worker?

Tags: json, service, get, service-worker, worker

Could someone tell me How to fetch data from php file using service worker?
for example I want to read the data from http://example.com/get-data.php using service worker

Comment: I would assume "http://example.com/get-data.php" is simply a "URL" that returns some "data" in its "response".  If so, it doesn't matter if the URL happens to be implemented in PHP, or a PHP file.  I would also assume your main goal is to "get the data", in which case I'd do a simple XHR.  But if you're really interested in reading data from a "Web Service Worker", there are many good tutorials.  For example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch("https://example.com/get-data.php")
.then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(myJson) {
    pn = JSON.stringify(myJson);
    console.log(pn);
});
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code as an answer, explain how it works and how it solves the problem of the question.